# Mouse cursor are not shown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent

I'm using the following code and want that the cursor will be shown
when the data is loaded ,why I don't see it on the screen ?Since currently nothing happen.
When I debug it I see that the code is invoked but nothing happen on the screen...

```
onButtonCommand(){

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;

            }));

            //Get service Data
            _Model.SerivceData();

           Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
               System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
           }));
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling method **asynchronously** (using *BeginInvoke*). Instead call it **synchronously** (using *Invoke*).

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor =
                     System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;

}));
```

BeginInvoke enqueue delegate on dispatcher and will execute it based on dispatcher priority asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks now I see it Voted UP! but the problem is that I call to service which the user have a pop-up which he should put the user and pass and I see it before but when the data is loeded I dont see it at all...when the data is loded I cannot even move with the cursor on the screen,any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @John - That's completely different question (not related to mouse cursor). To answer that we need more of the code you posted. Please post separate question with relevant code to reproduce an issue. (Kindly refrain from asking follow up questions which are not related to original question in comments otherwise your question won't be presented to larger audience here).